# Corruption of export using Merge feature in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, gdal-merge

Using QGIS 3.2.0 - Bonn
I'm getting a nasty corruption when trying to use the **Merge** feature to pull together a selection of .map (OziExplorer) files and merge into a single **.bmp** file. They load in perfectly into QGIS -

[image]

Then I select them all as input layers, change the data type to **'Byte'** I assume that's the right one for **.bmp** - as **'Float32'** default does not work?

[image]

Then I get an **.bmp** export of 4GB, but this odd corruption occurs:

[image]

If I switch to **.tif** - export works perfect 5.42GB

[image]

Am I just using the incorrect '**Output data type**' ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this was due to 4GB limit or resolution limit on bmp files, I just stuck with tif in the end which avoided above issue.